# AChartEngine - Move Y axis title?

Tags: android, title, achartengine

Is it possible to move the y and x axis title somehow? I want to have it in the corners, Y in upper left corner of graph and X in bottom right corner?

How can this be solved? Is it possible?

OR another way, is it possible to change "one" of the labeltextsize on the YAxis could also be a solution?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: code added but dont think it will say anything, i want to have kN in the upperleft corner as title and not as label or as label and different size as the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one now by adding a ExitText or TextView into my RelativeLayout and removed X/YTitle setting in achartengine, in this way i could add the TextView where i want it with setPadding!